# Flexslider and IE8 Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, flexslider

I am getting an error in IE8 "Object doesn't support this property or method" and my Flexslider is not running the script. I've looked through all of the similarly asked questions and double checked their solutions such as checking for trailing commas, removing 'defer' from the flexslider.js call, proper HTML and DOM calls, and made sure that jQuery is only being called once on the page.

There is a handful of other scripts being called before this so I moved it to before them, no avail. Then tried removing the other scripts completely so that only jQuery and Flexslider are being called, which means it isn't a conflict between seperate scripts.

Here is the code.

```
<script src="/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
</script>
```

The line causing the error is `$('.flexslider').flexslider();`

Maybe I've just been looking at this for too long and I'm missing something obvious, but this solution is evading me.

You can view the development site here for right now (link removed, issue has been fixed).

UPDATE: I removed the 'defer' from the flexslider.js call and it is now erroring out in all browsers, re-adding the `defer` when calling it fixes the issue for modern browsers, but might be why it cannot be loaded in IE8.

Comment: On Flexslider's site, they use jquery 1.6.2 as an example, try replacing your local 1.8.0 reference to `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js`. My guess is your script references are what is throwing IE off. I also see two references to `jqery.tools`. Try to isolate that slider to assure yourself that outside references aren't the issue.

Comment: Thanks @ElliotM! I was accidentally calling two versions of jquery.tools (one was hard coded and the other was being populated by our CMS so I didn't notice the doubling). After removing the 2nd call to jquery.tools the flexslider worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*For the sake of formality*

IE doesn't handle duplicate javascript references as well as other mainstream browsers, from looking at the testing site, you can see two references to `jquery.tools`. This may very be causing the annoying error.

Hope this helped. (Looks like it did)